# Resolve duplicate class dependency - gradle

Tags: android, gradle, speech-recognition, gcloud

I've been looking for a solution for quite some times but no luck.
I have google cloud speech api and google cloud translation api's added on the same project. Removing any of the dependencies builds the project but keeping both of them shows duplicate class error and I don't have exact clue how to solve this.

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
// Support libraries
implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"

// gRPC
implementation "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:$grpcVersion"
implementation "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:$grpcVersion"
implementation "io.grpc:grpc-stub:$grpcVersion"
implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
protobuf 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.8.0'

// OAuth2 for Google API
implementation('com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.7.0') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}

//Translation
 implementation('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.12.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
annotationProcessor 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.12.0'

// Tests
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'}
```

tried :

```
  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'project.properties'

}
```

nothing resolved.

Errors:

```
 Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite found in modules protobuf-java-3.4.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder found in modules protobuf-java-3.4.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
```

Which classes should I exclude and what should I do for the gradle properties?

Comment: why do you have the word protobuf instead of implementation for'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.8.0' ?

Comment: because google cloud sample has it this way and it works. :)

Comment: @Rifat were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @Omolara After opening issue on GitHub, recommended method solved this particular issue but crashed on run-time. Then That project appeared to have even more issues on upgraded android studio. So I gave up on that. Meanwhile I tested these dependencies with Kotline and it appeared to work without this particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue

adding :

exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf'

to

```
 implementation('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.12.0') {
            exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
            exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
            exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf'  

        }
        annotationProcessor 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.12.0'
    }
```

and making sure having these properties worked for me :

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'project.properties'

}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can convert your project to androidx by clicking option migrate to androidx under navigate option . May be this will help .

Comment: no it does not solve the issue. Why did you think converting to androidX is the solution?

Comment: I think may be the dependency is conflicting with support library . So migrating androidx will solve the issue.

Comment: its related to protobuf and translation, these are support libraries and those has no relation with those support libraries.